# SegmentedControl Always Zero

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to build an application that rolls dice. Nothing fancy at all. However, I'm using a segmented control to determine the number of dice and the sides of the dice.

Here is the `RollPressed` code.

```
#import "DiceBrain.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (readonly) DiceBrain *brain;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (DiceBrain *) brain {
    if (!brain) brain = [[DiceBrain alloc] init];
    return brain;
}

- (IBAction)RollPressed:(id)sender {
    int num_dice = dice.selectedSegmentIndex;
    int num_sides = sides.selectedSegmentIndex;
    NSLog(@"Number of Dice is %u and Number of Sides is %u", num_dice, num_sides);
    int result = [self.brain RollDice:num_dice Sides: num_sides];
    display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
}

@end
```

According to NSLog there, I'm always using a zero. Of course, actuating using this logic to roll the dice results in the display showing me something like `3.82652e-308.` 
The logic used to roll the dice is

```
- (int)RollDice:(int)dice Sides:(int)num_sides{
    total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dice; i++) {
        total += (arc4random() % num_sides) + 1;
    }

    return total;
}
```

What could cause the segmented control to give me such funky results?

Comment: Is the segmented control hooked up through IB? Is it a property that you then set yourself programmatically?

Comment: I hooked the segments up in IB, abut I managed to hook them up incorrectly somehow. A mistake that I checked for and though was okay, but StackOverflow made me check it again and find the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your IBOutlets for `sides` and `dice` are not connected.

Check their value; it's probably NULL.